# How to insert an image over a background image using html? But it should be responsive

Tags: html, css, background-image

I tried to do this, but I'm getting the image2 and text below the background image. I tried using `position` tag, but it does not make my web page responsive.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row" >
     <div class="cols12"> 
         <img style="height: 350px; width: 100%;"         src="image1.jpg">
         <img style="height: 200px;" src="image2.jpg">
         <h2>HELLOO</h2>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don’t have an actual _background image_ here, just two `img` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background image is set in CSS:

```
cols12 {
    background-image: url("image1.jpg");
}
```

Then you can remove the first image tag in your HTML.

I think you should style everything in CSS, but that is your choice..

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

EDIT:

If you insist in using inline css, then:

```
<div class="row" >
    <div class="cols12" style="background-image: url('image1.jpg')">
        <img style="height: 200px;" src="image2.jpg">
        <h2>HELLOO</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, in CSS:

```
background: url(image1.jpg);
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

You just have to experiment - and use the w3schools CSS reference.

Comment: Its not working. I got my image2 on background image but the background image is not fitting properly. Its kinda zoomed.

Comment: Check out `background-size` - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp - set it `cover`I think. Experiment :)

Answer (score -1):

You can make your images responsive by adding bootstrap. No need to download it, just go to the bootstrap website, get the link, and link to the bootstrap css file in your html doc. Then, you can make your images responsive by adding this class to your image elements: .img-responsive.

So, your image would look like this in html:

```
<img class="img-responsive" style="height: 200px;" src="image2.jpg">
```

Using bootstrap is an easy way to make your site responsive.